# How to use photo as character

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am wanting to write a program so that whenever I hit a certain letter/character, it deletes the character you put in and replaces it with a picture. So instead of typing with letters, it types with pictures, or symbols if I can change my pictures to symbols. I hope that makes sense.

I have no clue where to start for using the photos. All I have is this:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

'List compiled by Ryan Wells at wellsr.com

 Private Const VK_LBUTTON = &H1 'Left mouse button
 Private Const VK_RBUTTON = &H2 'Right mouse button
 Private Const VK_CANCEL = &H3 'Control-break processing
 Private Const VK_MBUTTON = &H4 'Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
 Private Const VK_BACK = &H8 'BACKSPACE key
 Private Const VK_TAB = &H9 'TAB key
 Private Const VK_CLEAR = &HC  'CLEAR key
 Private Const VK_RETURN = &HD  'ENTER key
 Private Const VK_SHIFT = &H10 'SHIFT key
 Private Const VK_CONTROL = &H11 'CTRL key
 Private Const VK_MENU = &H12 'ALT key
 Private Const VK_PAUSE = &H13 'PAUSE key
 Private Const VK_CAPITAL = &H14 'CAPS LOCK key
 Private Const VK_ESCAPE = &H1B 'ESC key
 Private Const VK_SPACE = &H20 'SPACEBAR
 Private Const VK_PRIOR = &H21 'PAGE UP key
 Private Const VK_NEXT = &H22 'PAGE DOWN key
 Private Const VK_END = &H23 'END key
 Private Const VK_HOME = &H24 'HOME key
 Private Const VK_LEFT = &H25 'LEFT ARROW key
 Private Const VK_UP = &H26 'UP ARROW key
 Private Const VK_RIGHT = &H27 'RIGHT ARROW key
 Private Const VK_DOWN = &H28 'DOWN ARROW key
 Private Const VK_SELECT = &H29 'SELECT key
 Private Const VK_PRINT = &H2A 'PRINT key
 Private Const VK_EXECUTE = &H2B 'EXECUTE key
 Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C 'PRINT SCREEN key
 Private Const VK_INSERT = &H2D 'INS key
 Private Const VK_DELETE = &H2E 'DEL key
 Private Const VK_HELP = &H2F 'HELP key
 Private Const VK_0 = &H30 '0 key
 Private Const VK_1 = &H31 '1 key
 Private Const VK_2 = &H32 '2 key
 Private Const VK_3 = &H33 '3 key
 Private Const VK_4 = &H34 '4 key
 Private Const VK_5 = &H35 '5 key
 Private Const VK_6 = &H36 '6 key
 Private Const VK_7 = &H37 '7 key
 Private Const VK_8 = &H38 '8 key
 Private Const VK_9 = &H39 '9 key
 Private Const VK_A = &H41 'A key
 Private Const VK_B = &H42 'B key
 Private Const VK_C = &H43 'C key
 Private Const VK_D = &H44 'D key
 Private Const VK_E = &H45 'E key
 Private Const VK_F = &H46 'F key
 Private Const VK_G = &H47 'G key
 Private Const VK_H = &H48 'H key
 Private Const VK_I = &H49 'I key
 Private Const VK_J = &H4A 'J key
 Private Const VK_K = &H4B 'K key
 Private Const VK_L = &H4C 'L key
 Private Const VK_M = &H4D 'M key
 Private Const VK_N = &H4E 'N key
 Private Const VK_O = &H4F 'O key
 Private Const VK_P = &H50 'P key
 Private Const VK_Q = &H51 'Q key
 Private Const VK_R = &H52 'R key
 Private Const VK_S = &H53 'S key
 Private Const VK_T = &H54 'T key
 Private Const VK_U = &H55 'U key
 Private Const VK_V = &H56 'V key
 Private Const VK_W = &H57 'W key
 Private Const VK_X = &H58 'X key
 Private Const VK_Y = &H59 'Y key
 Private Const VK_Z = &H5A 'Z key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD0 = &H60 'Numeric keypad 0 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD1 = &H61 'Numeric keypad 1 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD2 = &H62 'Numeric keypad 2 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD3 = &H63 'Numeric keypad 3 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD4 = &H64 'Numeric keypad 4 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD5 = &H65 'Numeric keypad 5 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD6 = &H66 'Numeric keypad 6 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD7 = &H67 'Numeric keypad 7 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD8 = &H68 'Numeric keypad 8 key
 Private Const VK_NUMPAD9 = &H69 'Numeric keypad 9 key
 Private Const VK_SEPARATOR = &H6C 'Separator key
 Private Const VK_SUBTRACT = &H6D 'Subtract key
 Private Const VK_DECIMAL = &H6E 'Decimal key
 Private Const VK_DIVIDE = &H6F 'Divide key
 Private Const VK_F1 = &H70 'F1 key
 Private Const VK_F2 = &H71 'F2 key
 Private Const VK_F3 = &H72 'F3 key
 Private Const VK_F4 = &H73 'F4 key
 Private Const VK_F5 = &H74 'F5 key
 Private Const VK_F6 = &H75 'F6 key
 Private Const VK_F7 = &H76 'F7 key
 Private Const VK_F8 = &H77 'F8 key
 Private Const VK_F9 = &H78 'F9 key
 Private Const VK_F10 = &H79 'F10 key
 Private Const VK_F11 = &H7A 'F11 key
 Private Const VK_F12 = &H7B 'F12 key
 Private Const VK_F13 = &H7C 'F13 key
 Private Const VK_F14 = &H7D 'F14 key
 Private Const VK_F15 = &H7E 'F15 key
 Private Const VK_F16 = &H7F 'F16 key
 Private Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90 'NUM LOCK key
 Private Const VK_SCROLL = &H91 'SCROLL LOCK key
 Private Const VK_LSHIFT = &HA0 'Left SHIFT key
 Private Const VK_RSHIFT = &HA1 'Right SHIFT key
 Private Const VK_LCONTROL = &HA2 'Left CONTROL key
 Private Const VK_RCONTROL = &HA3 'Right CONTROL key
 Private Const VK_LMENU = &HA4 'Left MENU key
 Private Const VK_RMENU = &HA5 'Right MENU key
 Private Const VK_PLAY = &HFA 'Play key
 Private Const VK_ZOOM = &HFB 'Zoom key

'REMINDER: To remind yourself how to use these keys
' with the GetAsyncKeyState function, please visit:
' http://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/GetAsyncKeyState-vba-to-wait-until-a-key-is-pressed/

Public Sub Gnommish()
    Do Until GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F9)
        'exit when F9 key is pressed
        DoEvents
        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A) Then
            'if A key is pressed
            'Replace "A" with picture
        ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_B) Then
            'if B key is pressed
            'Replace "B" with picture
        End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Create a custom bitmap font that displays photos instead of characters. Here's a site that may help: https://snowb.org/ For symbols, set the font to Wingdings or another symbol font.

Comment: @JohnKorchok is there a tutorial on how to use the site, how to map the pic to the letter, do i need to resize my pic before i map it to the letter?

Comment: @JohnKorchok How would I then go from that to Word? And is there a way to use that so if I added the addon to another computer, I don't need to also move over that file that I would get from snowb.org?

Comment: Once you create the font, then you can use it in Word or any other program. Just select the font using the Home>Font dropdown. You would have to copy the font along with any add-in that used it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A) Then
    'if A key is pressed
    'Replace "A" with picture
    Application.Selection.TypeBackspace
    Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\path\to\files\pic.png"
```

Comment: That would work, but how would I do it if I then moved the addon to another computer that doesn't have the files? Could I use the UserForm thing in VBA to store the pictures and then add them from there?

Comment: If you decide to insert pictures instead of using a bitmap font, you can store pictures in AutoText in a Word template.

Comment: @JohnKorchok But how would I do it if I wanted it to be an add on that other people could download, so they don't need to do anything extra other than just downloading the add on itself and then using it?

Answer (score 0):

Word doesn't have an add-in file format. Instead, you save as a .dotm file and install the file into the Word Startup folder. The .dotm can hold the picture content in AutoText.

You probably want to be using an installer to do this, as the Startup folder is inside a hidden folder. The default location in Windows is **C:\Users[YourActualUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP**. On a Mac, its **MacHD/Users/[YourActualUserName]/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Startup/Word**.

Comment: So I just need to add the pictures/characters into autotext, then when I make the program into an add-in, it should still be able to use those pictures, correct?

Comment: Please re-read my reply, I've already answered your question. "Word doesn't have an add-in file format. Instead, you save as a .dotm file and install the file into the Word Startup folder. The .dotm can hold the picture content in AutoText."